# Pass a python list to a django template

Tags: python, html, css, django

I'm new to `django` and I'm trying to pass a list that I created in a python function but its not showing nothing and don't understand why? I'm trying to send a simple list with only numbers to make it more clear to see. If I can solve that I will try to do in a different way but essentially this is the core problem

**views.py**

```
def csv_empresas(request):
lista_nums = ["1","2","3","4"]

print (lista)

return render_to_response('preparar_pdf.html',{'lista': lista_nums})
```

**html:**

```
<body>
<header>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Crear pdf</h1>
    </div>
</header>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <form action="" class="">
        <div class="row col-md-9 col-lg-12 bigsep">
            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'csv_empresas' %}">Crea empresas</a>
        </div>

        <div class="row col-md-9 col-lg-12 ">
            <h3>Selecciona las empresas que necesites</h3>  
        </div>

        <div class="row col-md-9 col-lg-12 bigsep">
            <select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true"  multiple data-actions-box="true" data-style="btn">
            </select>

            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-md" type="button" onclick="paso2()">Siguiente</button>
        </div>
    </form>

    <div class="container">
        <ul>        
        {% for empresa in lista %}
            <li>{{empresa}}</li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from creadorpdf import views

  urlpatterns = [
      url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
      url(r'^$',views.index,name='index'),
      url(r'^subir_archivos', views.subir_archivos,name='subir_archivos'),
      url(r'^preparar_pdf',views.preparar_pdf,name='preparar_pdf'),
      url(r'^csv_empresas',views.preparar_pdf,name='csv_empresas')
      ]
```

Comment: Did you tried `render(request, 'preparar_pdf.html',{'lista': lista_nums})` ? will help in case of `request context`

Comment: I tried now and its not working too :(

Comment: You are trying `print(lista)` in between which is still not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have misspelled in url

Change

```
url(r'^csv_empresas',views.preparar_pdf,name='csv_empresas')
```

to

```
url(r'^csv_empresas',views.csv_empresas,name='csv_empresas')
```

Comment: Its true that was the error, tnx itzMEonTV for the help :)