# Passing a python list and display correctly

Tags: python, django

I am trying to pass a list from a csv and fill a select menu in html using django. The format of my csv is like that `["otis","Otis"],["bel","Bel"]..` The problem is when I put all the elements in the select the result is a bit weird and don't know how to display correctly, because I want to put in the value = otis and in the option Otis.

This is my template:

```
{% for empresa in lista %}

    <option value="{{empresa}}">{{empresa[empresa]}}

    </option> #The result is in the html select ['otis','Otis']
                                                ['bel','Bel']

{% endfor %}
```

And this is my function:

```
def csv_empresas(request):
    lista = []

    with open('media/empresas.csv') as csvfile:
        lector = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',',quotechar='|')
        for row in lector:
            lista.append(row)

    return render(request,'preparar_pdf.html',{"lista": lista})
```

If u need more information ask me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass a python list to a django template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44041145/pass-a-python-list-to-a-django-template)

Comment: Im in the same app but with a different problem now.

Comment: Please use relevant tags only. This question has nothing to do with HTML or CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if square brackets were valid syntax in Django templates, which they aren't, why would you use `empresa[empresa]`? That doesn't make sense from any point of view.

What you need here is the first value in the sublist to be used as the value, and the second as the display value. That's simple to achieve:

```
<option value="{{ empresa.0 }}">{{ empresa.1 }}</option>
```